# pass a PDO db object instance to other class function

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have an PDO object in an included file and when i use it in main page it works great.
And when i pass it into an object to use it inside of them it simply dont work.

I've tried directly and with reference (function xxxx(&dbd){ this->$db = &dbd }), simply dont work, but if i pass another type of value (as a string) that works perfect. If i send a $db = "olaola" it works but if it is an PDO it fails. I'm a newbie in php and in english, so be patient please :P

included file:

```
$username = "root";
$password = "*****";
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "dbname";
$db = NULL;
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

in main:

```
$pagMenu = new pages($db);
```

in pages class:

```
class pages {

    private $db;

    function __construct($db) { 
        $this->$db = $db;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly? What does or doesn't it do?

Comment: how do you access the $db object in your class pages? (you cant access it from outside because its private in your example)

Comment: Using $this->db in the pages class should have the same results as using $db in the main program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do

```
$this->db = $db;
```

instead of

```
$this->$db = $db;
```

The second form is a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), which means that you are assigning the value of the parameter to a variable named as the content of the variable, which will return an error if that content is a PDO object.

Comment: Tks a lot. By the way, do you know why i can use de db object in main but when i use it in "pages" class won't work? The fetchAll of resulting query in pages function return an array empty and in main result with the values.

Comment: Using the $db object in main should give the same results as using $this->db in the pages class, because they are the same thing. Not sure what the error could be.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax is:

```
    $this->db = $db;
```

Not `$this->$db`.

Comment: Well spotted. Do you know why it was working with the string?

Comment: Because a string resolves to a proper "variable variable", or rather "variable property" here. An object is not a valid variable name.

Comment: You should put that in the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Static syntax

```
$self::$variableName
```

This syntax

```
$this->variableName
```